# Error while attaching file into a process

Tags: java, jvm

I'm trying to attach agent file to specific process
My code:

```java
   try{
       VirtualMachine virtualMachine = VirtualMachine.attach(pid);
       virtualMachine.loadAgent(agentFile.getAbsolutePath());
       System.out.println("Agent loaded!");

       virtualMachine.detach();
       System.out.println("detached");

   } catch (IOException | AttachNotSupportedException | AgentLoadException | 
            AgentInitializationException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

Error:

```
       com.sun.tools.attach.AttachNotSupportedException: Unable to enqueue operation: the target VM does 
        not support attach mechanism

        at sun.tools.attach.WindowsVirtualMachine.<init>(WindowsVirtualMachine.java:64)
        at sun.tools.attach.WindowsAttachProvider.attachVirtualMachine(WindowsAttachProvider.java:69)
        at com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine.attach(VirtualMachine.java:208)
        at pl.alpaqdev.client.Util.attach(Util.java:46)
        at pl.alpaqdev.client.Main.main(Main.java:25)
```

I also tried `ByteBuddyAgent.attach(agentFile, pid);` with using [byte-buddy](https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy), but I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Wich JVM are you using? as not all of them supports the attach mechanism

Comment: I'm using JDK 1.8.0_251, I don't know if this is what you want, I'm a beginner. Also it works with other jars but this one might be protected against attaching or something.

Comment: have you tried using the '-XX:+StartAttachListener' argument?

Comment: still the same error